# What is the fastest way of getting PolicyId from an Asset Fingerprint?

Tags: token

Is it possible to retrieve the policyId from an 'asset fingerprint' without any api request to an external source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, the fingerprint is the hash of the policy id and name concatenated. Cryptographic hashes can't be reversed.